# Advanced Product Options magento extension

Tags: magento

I am using "Advanced Product Options Magento Extension".
(http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-product-options.html)

I created product using this extension and placed the order.

In admin panel order summary, SKU format is something like

"20150420-7850015-7850023-7850028" (group of SKU separated by hyphen)

I need to separate this by ',' (comma) instead of '-' (hyphen) so want help to find the file which is used to concat all SKU by '-' (hyphen) and inserting this format into table.

Comment: As this is paid extension, you can contact extension support for this.

Comment: As Pankaj said go for the support if they dont you can take refund, here is a similar one and they offer life time free support - http://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-custom-options-pricing-curtains-blinds-pipes.html

Answer (score 0):

In **/app/code/local/MageWorx/CustomOptions/Model/Observer.php**

Find this line of code:

```
$skuReplacement = implode('-', $skuReplacement);
```

and change it to:

```
$skuReplacement = implode(',', $skuReplacement);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the "-" to ",", you should edit the file `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Abstract.php` and change "-" to "," in the first line in the method `getOptionSku`:

```
$skuDelimiter = '-';
```

to:

```
$skuDelimiter = ',';
```

Thanks